# Cat here document escape all variable but one

Tags: bash, escaping, eof, cat, heredoc

I have to write to a file with some bash script. To substitute the variables we can use simply `EOF` and we escape the substitution with `\`. But, I want to escape everything, so, I can use `'EOF'` and also want to substitute one variable, then how?.

```
 cat > myfile <<'EOF'
    $a
    $b
    $c
    $d
    $e
    $f
    $g
   .....
   .....
   $multiple lines like this
   EOF
```

I want to substitute only one variable let `$c` with it's value. How can I do in this case?. I can't use `\` without quoting `EOF` escaping all the lines as there are many lines.

I just want to escape all the variable substitution(`'EOF'`) but want to substitute one variable with its value(How?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid escaping the many variables but still substitute for one of them, try:

```
$ cat script
sed 's/$c/3/' >myfile <<'EOF'
    $a
    $b
    $c
   $multiple lines like this
EOF
```

Let's run the script and examine the output file:

```
$ bash script
$ cat myfile 
    $a
    $b
    3
   $multiple lines like this
```

#### Alternative

This version allows for a variable `$c` and, thus, may be more flexible:

```
$ cat script
c=New
sed "s/\$c/$c/" >myfile <<'EOF'
    $a
    $b
    $c
   $multiple lines like this
EOF
```

Execution of this results in:

```
$ bash script
$ cat myfile 
    $a
    $b
    New
   $multiple lines like this
```

Comment: Nice!, it worked!. As I said I just want to substitute only one variable and it worked. What if I want to substitute more than one, let it be 2 variable substitution, any idea?

Comment: I spent lot of time trying to find it, this really helps me a lot. I anticipate I might have to substitute more than one variable going forward and wondering how to use `sed` in this case...

Comment: @user465465 To substitute for both `$c` and `$d`, use `sed "s/\$c/$c/; s/\$d/$d/" >myfile <<'EOF'`.

Comment: Great, thanks!. Probably I should start using sed than cat.

Comment: @user465465 Glad it worked for you.   If you are going to do much shell scripting, both `sed` and `awk` are useful tools to know.